# Prolog Returning Internal Variable Name in Confluence Checker

Tags: prolog

I am trying to code a confluence checker in Prolog for an assignment. This part of the code is in charge of creating the critical pairs and is working correctly as far as I can see. The problem is that whenever we call the main function "superpose" we get the internal names of the variables (beginning with _G) and not the X, Y, Z, etcetera. For example:

```
?- superpose(4,12,Q).
_G6993+ee+_G6991[e,_G6991,e+_G6991]
Q = [e+ (_G6993+e), 1] .
```

And I would like to see the answer in terms of X,Y,Z, etcetera; rather than _G84119. Is there a simple way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

```
rule(1,e+X, X).
rule(2,Y+f, Y).
rule(3,parent(parent(Z)), grandparent(Z)).
rule(4,e+X,1).
rule(12,Y+e,1).
rule(5,0+X,X).
rule(7,((-Y)+Y),0).
rule(9,Y+Y,0).
rule(10,X+X,X).
rule(11,(X+Y)+Z,X+(Y+Z)).

get_Subterms( Expression, PartialResult, Result):-
   atom(Expression),!,
   Result= [Expression|PartialResult].
get_Subterms( Expression, PartialResult, Result):-
   var(Expression),!,
   Result= [Expression|PartialResult].
get_Subterms( Expression, PartialResult, Result ):-
   Expression =.. [_, SubExpA],
   get_Subterms(SubExpA,[],PartResA),
   append(PartResA, [Expression|PartialResult], Result),
   !.
get_Subterms( Expression, PartialResult, Result ):-
   !,
   Expression =.. [_, SubExpA, SubExpB],
   get_Subterms(SubExpA,[],PartResA),
   get_Subterms(SubExpB,[],PartResB),
   append(PartResA, PartResB, PartResC),
   append(PartResC, [Expression|PartialResult], Result).

superpose( RuleN, RuleM, CriticalPair):-
   rule(RuleN,L1,R1),
   rule(RuleM,L2, _),
   get_Subterms(L1,[],Bits),
   match(Bits,L2),
   CriticalPair=[L1,R1].

match([],_,_,_):-
   false.
match([Head|Tail],Target):-
   Tail=[],
   unify(Head,Target).
match([Head|Tail],Target):-
   Tail\=[],
   unify(Head,Target)
;  match(Tail,Target).
```

----UPDATE----

I managed to get a better output with:

```
 superpose( RuleN, RuleM, CriticalPair):-
    rule(RuleN,L1,R1),
    rule(RuleM,L2, R2),
    get_Subterms(L1,[],Bits),
    match(Bits,L2),
    CriticalPair=[L1,R1],
    portray_clause(CriticalPair).


?- superpose(1,2,C).
[e+ (A+f), A+f].
C = [e+ (_G9035+f), _G9035+f]
```

Is there a way to "quiet" prolog's second output? (the one with the C=...)

Comment: If by "quiet" you mean not show C binding then just use `superpose(1,2,_)` as a query.

Answer (score 2):

Prolog systems don't usually save the names of variables when compiling a file. For a Prolog compiler and runtime, variables *names* are not relevant, what's important is variable *sharing* (in a term such as a clause). For example, a Prolog compiler will generate the same code for the following clauses:

```
foo(X, Y, X).
foo(A, B, A).
foo(Bar, _, Bar).
```

But the first two clauses will result in singleton warnings.

The compilation of the code you posted most likely resulted in singleton variable warnings. For example, for the fourth and fifth clauses of the `rule/3` predicate. A singleton warning can result from a programmer typo where a variable name is misspelled or from a true singleton variable, which can be then replaced by the anonymous variable, `_`.

Also, the code you posted is missing the definition of some predicate such as `unify/2`, which prevents trying to reproduce the query results.